# Ghost of Winterbash Past hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I noticed that [this user on Sustainable Living SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/917/dave-baldwin#winter-bash) has got the 'Ghost of Winterbash Past' hat and I'm very much wondering how he got it.

My first guess was that the hat can only be earned if you did something special during Winterbash 2012, but.... Sustainability SE didn't exist then. I checked several other beta sites that didn't exist during the previous Winterbash (Tridion, Reverse Engineering, Italian Language), and there is no user with this hat there.

The second strange thing is that the user hasn't logged in since november 24th, so I guess it was assigned at the start of Winterbash.

Is it a bug that this user got the hat? Or is this just part of the mystery surrounding the Ghost of Winterbash past?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must (spoiler):

> earn the Necromancer badge.

Comment: I figured that much after taking another look at the user's profile.

Comment: Which is *exactly* how you got the same hat last year. :-) I just didn't want to give that away.

Answer (score 3):

You earn the hat the same way you could [earn it last year](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/what-are-the-secret-hats-for-2012).

Comment: There are so many hats this year. We have the largest collection right now, Martijn.